# Low Quality Images in spot motion canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I am using a jquery plugin that utilities canvas to draw up spot motion animations.(http://arena.palamago.com.ar/spotMotion/)

I know that in this instance i can use animated GIF images, but the image types i use in future will be requiring higher quality and transparency.

If you look at the jsfiddle below you will see the images are not sharp, i am on a retina display and they look even worse, the original image is 800px. Canvas is not scaling the images high enough fo some unknown reason. I am fairly new to canvas and have seen a few methods for up scaling but have had no luck in getting a better result.

I looked at canvas width and canvas style width

```
canvas.width = "200";
canvas.height = "200"; // allow 40 pixels for status bar on iOS
canvas.style.width = "100px";
canvas.style.height = "100px";
```

I also looked at css image rendering techniques

```
canvas { image-rendering:optimizeQuality;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TsAzP/1/

Another attempt but i just cant seem to intergrate it with this plugin.

```
function enhanceContext(canvas, context) {
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

   if (ratio > 1) {
    canvas.width = width * ratio;
    canvas.height = height * ratio;
    canvas.style.width = width + "px";
    canvas.style.height = height + "px";
    context.scale(ratio, ratio);
   }
}
```

I have seen some very complicated methods with people writing up-scaling algorithms, i just dont understand how to put it together. If anyone knows how to improve image quality please spare me some time.

Thank you

Comment: SVG + CSS animations?

Comment: Could work, but i want to apply this to far more detailed animations, things like characters walking, or trees growing money. Cartoon like things, this goes a bit beyond SVG i think?

Remember i could also use GIF's to do this but this is more of a principal that i want to upscale canvas drawn images.

Comment: SVGs can be complex. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=svg&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=olX1UrKrHYbd4QSthoC4Aw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ) shows all kids of images as svgs. [Cool list](http://www.creativebloq.com/design/examples-svg-7112785)

Comment: This complex? http://goo.gl/zskws2

Comment: Yeah, why not? Just a bunch of gradients and beziers and paths.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

The cause is that the source image is too large to reduce in size in a single down-scale.

The browser typically uses bi-linear interpolation over bi-cubic interpolation when it comes to the canvas element.

Bi-linear interpolation analyses 2x2 pixels while bi-cubic uses 4x4 (in down-sampling functioning as a low-pass filter to create an average pixel). If the image size reduction is too steep there is simply not enough pixels to consider for averaging and the result will be in part "choppy" or pixelated.

### Solution

To solve you can do one of the following steps:

1. Prepare the image(s) at a smaller size in an image editor (for example Photoshop) and scale the image to the destination size you want to use (ref. retina display).
2. Process the image on client before drawing it by creating an off-screen canvas and scale down the image in 2-3 steps.

The first step could be a better solution for a variety of reasons such as:

- Processing of the image (for size) does not happen on client
- Quality in resulting image (easier to post-process)
- Bandwidth reduction (less data to transfer)
- Faster processing of the image (in use) on client
- Saves on battery (less processing involved)

As for the second step: There's too much code in the fiddle (TL; TR), but the principle is as follows (and it's not so complicated):

```
/// create two temporary canvas elements
var ocanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),  /// off-screen canvas
    tcanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),  /// temp canvas
    octx = ocanvas.getContext('2d'),
    tctx = ocanvas.getContext('2d');
```

Then we do a first step-down scaling of the image - for this example we will do it twice which is the minimum needed. You might need a third step if the size difference is huge (you can normally calculate this by using a function of log etc., but I'll leave that out of the um, "equation" here):

```
/// use temp canvas (tcanvas) to scale for the first step
tcanvas.width = img.width * 0.5;    /// 50% allow good result with bi-linear
tcanvas.height = img.height * 0.5;

/// draw image into canvas
tctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, tcanvas.width, tcanvas.height);
```

The next step is just as simple as the above but with an absolute size:

```
/// set destination size
ocanvas.width = 200;
ocanvas.height = 200;

/// draw temp canvas into canvas
octx.drawImage(tcanvas, 0, 0, ocanvas.width, ocanvas.height);
```

You can now use `ocanvas` in your solution instead of `img`.

We use two canvases as we want to use the final `ocanvas` to replace `img` directly later at the proper size. If we used one canvas we would have to resize it in the final step which mean the canvas would be cleared.

If you do need a third step then you can reuse one of the canvases.

The added advantage here is that the browser won't need to scale anything when animating which reduces the load on the CPU/GPU.

I suggest also doing this down-scaling inside a function so that the temporary canvas references (except the one you need to use pf course, which you need to return) can be easily discarded by the browser after use (GC/memory wise).

Hope this helps!